# Change async workflow builder to count steps?

Tags: f#, monads

My understanding is that what a workflow builder does is that it first "builds" the expression, and then subsequently executes it.  So given that it first builds the expression, it should be able to count the number of `let!` statements before actually executing, right?  And then it should be able to inject some logging that monitors progress?  So is it possible to rework the `async` builder to automatically report progress and kill the `printfn` redundancy below?

```
 async {
   let! a = doSomething1 ()
   printfn "%d/%d" 1 4
   let! b = doSomething2 a
   printfn "%d/%d" 2 4
   let! c = doSomething3 b
   printfn "%d/%d" 3 4
   let! d = doSomething4 c
   printfn "%d/%d" 4 4
   return d
 }
```

For loops, I guess just assume that the whole loop is a single step.  Only top-level expressions count as steps here.

(Note if there's a way to do this without making a whole new workflow builder I guess that's fine too).

Note I've already gone through the path of a) making a "Task" iterator that just iterates tasks (but then you lose e.g. `use` handling, so it ended up being inadequate), and b) making a task counter, but that always had to be seeded and iterated manually so I'm hoping for something better.

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged the question with the tag *monads*, I'll start by a theoretical nitpick. What you want to do would not actually be a *monad*. The problem is that monads require certain laws (see [the Haskell page on monads](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws)). For F#, this means that the following two snippets should mean the same thing:

```
let computation1 = 
  async { let! x = m
          return x }
let computation2 = m
```

This would not be the case for the extension you suggest, because `computation1` has one more `let!` than `computation2`. Now, I do not think this is actually a problem - the logging could still be useful (even if it may give different results than you'd expect in some cases).

Adding this feature to F# async is not as easy - the problem is that you'd need to define your own type that replaces (or wraps) standard `Async<'T>`. The type needs to store the number of steps. If you can store the number of steps somewhere else (e.g. some mutable counter), then you just need to redefine the computation builder for `async`.

Here is a minimal example that does something like this - it just prints `"step"` for each `let!`:

```
// A custom computation builder that redirects all operations to
// the standard 'async' builder, but prints "step" in the Bind method
type LogAsyncBuilder() = 
  member x.Bind(c1, f) = async { 
    let! arg = c1
    printfn "step!" 
    return! f arg }
  member x.Return(v) = async.Return(v)
  member x.ReturnFrom(c) = async.ReturnFrom(c)

// An instance of our custom computation builder
let logAsync = LogAsyncBuilder()

// Example that prints 'step' 4 times (for every Bind - let!)
let doSomething n = logAsync {
  return n + 10 }

logAsync {
  let! a = doSomething 0
  let! b = doSomething a
  let! c = doSomething b
  let! d = doSomething c
  return d }
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: Yeah, it occurred to me after writing the question that it really didn't have anything specifically to do with async--all I really wanted was a step counter; conflating it with async steps was merely a domain detail.  However the crux of my question was more about *can my builder identify that there are* **N** *let! (/do!/for/whatever) top-level statements in my workflow without me having to specify that explicitly, and that it is currently executing step* **i** *of* **N**?  Is this possible?

Comment: (Preferably not including `use` as a top-level construct; such that any `let!`s within a `use` would be counted independently)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tuple `('a, int, int)` to track the current result, the total number of steps and the number executed so far. Then you could write a function to take the current state, and the next async function to execute e.g.

```
//create the initial state
let startCount steps = ((), 0, steps)

let withCount af (a, c, steps) = async {
    let nc = c + 1
    let! res = af a
    do printfn "%d %d" nc steps
    return (res, nc, steps)
}
```

`withCount` takes a function which returns the next async operation, and the current state. It creates the next workflow, increments the number of executed steps and prints the status before returning the new state.

You can then use it like:

```
async {
    let init = startCount 4
    let! t = withCount doSomething init
    let! t2 = withCount doSomething2 t
    let! (r, _, _) = withCount doSomething3 t2
    return r
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's basically the best option I've come up already.  It works in C# too.  I was hoping for something, really just as an excuse to use something where I'd be able to tell the boss we *need* F#, where I might be able to use workflows or some F#-specific features to eliminate the need to think about it *completely*.